# In the rational function field $K(x)|K$, the place at infinity $P_\infty$ has degree $1$

Tags: field-theory, arithmetic-geometry, function-fields

Let $P_\infty$ be the place at infinity at the rational function field $K(x)|K$.

I'm trying to prove that $\deg(P_\infty)=1$ (where $\deg(P_\infty):=[\mathcal{O}_\infty/P_\infty:K]$ and $\mathcal{O}_\infty$ is the valuation ring whose maximal ideal is $P_\infty$).

I know how to find the degree of the place $P_{p(x)}$ associated to an irreducible polynomial $p(x)\in K[x]$ by considering the natural isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_{p(x)}/P_{p(x)}\simeq K[x]/(p(x))$, so that:
$$\deg(P_{p(x)})=\deg(p(x))$$
For the case $P_\infty$, I can't see any analogous strategy.

Comment: Do you define $\deg(v)$ as $[ O_v/m_v : K]$ where $v$ is a discrete valuation on $K(x)$, trivial on $K$, $O_v= \{ f \in K(x),v(f)\ge 0\}, m_v=\{ f \in K(x),v(f)> 0\}$ ? (so the place is $v$ or $O_v$ or $m_v$ or the equivalence class of the $K$-homomorphism $O_v\to \overline{K}$ as you wish)

Comment: @reuns yes, that's how I define it

Comment: Then $x^{-1} K[x^{-1}]_{(x^{-1})}$ ($=$ the rational functions vanishing at $\infty$) is a place of degree $1$